# udev rule not being executed

Tags: linux, udev

I have the following device that `udevadm` lists as:

> looking at device
>   '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:09:00.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
>       KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
>       SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
>       DRIVER==""
>
> looking at parent device
>   '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:09:00.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/ttyUSB0':
>       KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
>       DRIVERS=="pl2303"
>       ATTRS{port_number}=="0"
>
> looking at parent device
>   '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:09:00.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0':
>       KERNELS=="6-2:1.0"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
>       DRIVERS=="pl2303"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
>       ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
>       ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

So I created the rule:

> KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", DRIVERS=="pl2303", KERNELS=="6-2:1.0", SYMLINK+="cc128serial"

this doesn't work.

However if I do:

> KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", DRIVERS=="pl2303", SYMLINK+="cc128serial"

then it works.
I tried with `KERNELS=="6*"` etc.. to no available

any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Did either of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: Maybe it's too late. But you may also want to see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285324/26714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article on writing udev scripts](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#udevinfo) (look for "invalid") indicates that the rule you would like to use is invalid because you try to match against attributes from two different parent levels: `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` (parent), and `KERNELS=="6-2:1.0"` (grandparent).

> ...while it is legal to combine the attributes from the device in
>   question and a single parent device, you cannot mix-and-match
>   attributes from multiple parent devices - your rule will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The parent device has `KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"` which I bet takes precedence over the parent's parent device `KERNELS=="6-2:1.0"`.

Any reason not to use the rule that works?

Comment: My understanding is that it should look for all combination going up. I should add that this rule was working perfectly fine with linux 2.6 (ubuntu 10.04). Rules stopped working when I upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.2). The reason I can't use the rule that "works" is because I have 3 identical USB device, and I can only distinguish them via the USB port they are plugged to

Comment: Let me suggest noting that you have 3 identical devices and must identify based on port in the original question.  That will help people understand what the underlying issue is.